# How to write into specific columns of a file using C++?

Tags: c++, string, file, ofstream

Using C++, I want to generate a file in which I have to add the line number to the end of each line. Some lines end after 13th character, some of them end after 32nd. But the line numbers should be in the end. A line is 80 characters long, the last number of the line should be in the 80th column of the line.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I initialize my file using ofstream, use C++.

Comment: There are several ways to accomplish this.  Is this homework?

Comment: No, I'm actually writing an IGES converter, which needs the line numbers in the end of each line and also specific data in specific column. I just minimized the problem so everybody can understand.

Comment: Do you know C++ at all?  Do  you have to use C++ in particular?

Comment: Yes I use C++ to solve numerical problems mainly. I'm unfamiliar with the string capabilities.- and I have to use C++ since my whole code was written in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's one way to go about it using a stringstream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int lineNum = 42;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << setw(80) << lineNum;
    ss.seekp(0);
    ss << "information for beginning of line";
    cout << ss.str() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Basically sets the stream to right align and pad to 80 chars, lays down your line number, and then seeks to the beginning of the line where you can output whatever you want.  If you keep writing a long line of data into the stream you'll overwrite your line number, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Pad each output line:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void
pad (std::string &line, unsigned int no, unsigned int len = 80)
{
  std::ostringstream n;

  n << no;

  line.resize (len - n.str().size (), ' ');
  line += n.str();
}

int
main ()
{
  std::string s ("some line");

  pad (s, 42, 80);
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```